# Let $V$ be a subspace of $\mathbb R^n$ and $A$ the M.R of $P_V$. Decide eigenvalues of $A$ and show $A$ is orthogonal diagonalizable.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\mathbb R^n$ be an inner product space with scalarproduct.

Let $V$ be a subspace of $\mathbb R^n$, $P_V: \mathbb R^n \rightarrow \mathbb R^n$ (projection of $\mathbb R^n$ on $V$) and $A$ the matrix representation of $P_V$ with respect to the standard basis in $\mathbb R^n$.

1) Decide the eigenvalues of $A$:

I know a vector $v \in \mathbb R^n$ is the direct product of $V$ and orthogonal complement to $V$, so the only eigenvalue is $1$ ? Every vector in $v \in V$ get projected to $v$, while every vector $v \notin V$ can be written $v = P_V(v) + z$ and get projected to $P_V(v)$, which is not a scalar multiple of $v$? (Can this be stated more rigorously?)

2) Show that $A$ is orthogonal diagonalizable:

I know that if $A$ is symmetric this is true. But how can I show $A$ has the property of being symmetric ?

Answer (score 3):

Since $P_V$ is a projection then we have
$$\Bbb R^n={\rm{im}} P_V\oplus \ker P_V$$
so if we take a basis
$$B=(e_1,\ldots,e_p,e_{p+1},\ldots,e_n)$$
adapted  to the last decomposition then we have
$$P_V(e_k)=e_k,\quad k=1,\ldots,p$$
and 
$$P_V(e_k)=0,\quad k=p+1,\ldots,n$$
hence $1$ and $0$ are the two eigenvalues of $P_V$ and the matrix of $P_V$ in the basis $B$ is
$$\operatorname{diag}(\underbrace{1,\ldots,1}_{p\;\text{times}},\underbrace{0,\ldots,0}_{n-p\;\text{times}})$$

Comment: Thanks ! How do you know $\mathbb R^n$ is the direct sum of kernel and image of $P_V$ ?

Comment: For every $x\in \Bbb R^n$ write
$$x=P_V(x)+(x-P_V(x))$$

Comment: Well done!${}{}{}$

Comment: Is the matrix $B$ consisting of the standard basis of $\mathbb R^n$ ? If $A$ is the matrix representation of $P_V$ with respect to the standard basis of $\mathbb R^n$ shouldn't $$A = [[P_V(e_1)]_{\epsilon},...,[P_V(e_n)]_{\epsilon}]$$ ?

Comment: where $e_i$ is a standard basis vector of $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: Can i change this matrix into a diagonal in standard basis ?

Comment: No $B$ isn't the standard basis but as I said it's adapted to the decomposition 
$$\Bbb R^n={\rm{im}} P_V\oplus \ker P_V$$ @user111854

Comment: So $B$ consist of the union of basis' for $im P_V$ and $\ker P_V$ ? What I should prove is that the matrix representation of $A$ with respect to the standard basis is orthogonal diagonalizable. As I remember $A$ is given by $[[P_V(e_1)]_{\epsilon}],..,[P_V(e_n)]_{\epsilon}]$ where $\epsilon = \{e_1,..,e_n\}$ denotes the standard basis of $\mathbb R^n$. But the matrix you find is the matrix $M_{\epsilon, B}(P_V)$, that is the matrix satisfying $[P_V(v)]_{\epsilon} = M_{\epsilon, B}(P_V)[v]_B$ ? This is not an exact answer ? I guess I've misunderstood something ...

Comment: We have proved that $P_V$ is diagonalizable and it's in fact orthogonal diagonalizable i.e. the matrix of $P_V$ is diagonal in an orthogonal basis: indeed $P_V$ is the orthogonal projection so
$${\rm{im}}(P_V)\perp\ker(P_V)$$ so we can make the basis $B$ orthogonal using the Gram-Schmidt's procedure.@user111854

Comment: Yes, but making the basis $B$ orthogonal doesn't change things ? $B$ is not neccesarily equal to the standard basis for $\mathbb R^n$ after applying the Gram-Schmidt procedure ? So the matrix we get is still not $$[[P_V(e_1)_{\epsilon},...,[P_V(e_n)_{\epsilon}]]$$ which is the matrix representation of $P_V$ ($A$) with respect to the standard basis of $\mathbb R^n$ ?

Comment: Can I make change of basis to $\epsilon$ (standard basis) to get an diagonal or symmetric matrix representation of $P_V$ with respect to $\epsilon$ given that the matrix representation with respect to $B$ is diagonal ?